# Project reference not working in VisualStudio2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a Solution with lots of projects and all but one of them are behaving. The one that is not working is a console application, and it relies on the C# Class Library project. I've added a reference to the library project and added the namespace (which I've checked is correct), but everywhere I reference the classes in my library, I get:

The type or namespace 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?).

The library project is building successfully (I can see the DLLs appear in the bin folder) and I've tried a project reference, and also a reference to the DLL itself. Neither works.

Also, all projects are set to build with a platform target of 'Any CPU'.

I've tried pretty much every suggestion I've come across on forums with no success. Can anyone shed some light on what's going wrong?

Thanks

> This solved the problem:

*The console application had a Target framework of `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`, whereas the library just had `.NET Framework 4`. I set the console app to `.NET Framework 4` and it all builds perfectly.*

Comment: Just my two cents. C# is case sensitive. Have you checked your namespace case?

Comment: Does the class have a public constructor?

Comment: have a look at antao's answer below - we regularly see that git merges mess up our project files.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

My bet is on a framework mismatch between your library and you app...
Check if your library is not building with a superior version than you app, or if your app is building with a Client profile flavor

Comment: Yep, you were spot on, I've put a full answer below - thanks for the tips Cédric

Comment: Thanks everyone, that was quick! :)

Yes, the console application had a Target framework of .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, whereas the library just had .NET Framework 4. I set the console app to ".NET Framework 4" and it all builds perfectly.

I wouldn't have thought to look there given the wording of the error so thanks for the tips. I guess it's one of those mistakes you only make once and remember it for next time (...?)

Thanks!

Comment: Oh my, i though i would spend a whole day trying to solve this, and then there is you :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem. I wished there was a more useful error when building indicating this problem... Gladly I found this post before losing a lot of time on it. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, because it worked for me: be sure you are typing the namespace of the library you're using, not the name of the class.

Comment: Exactly! For my case, it was that one project(build with .net 4.5.2) was referencing another one(build with .net 4.6.2) which had a superior .NET version.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I had 0 Errors but Build failed! And I was like.. "Wait! What!?" o.O

Comment: Thank you!  I was struggling with this between .net 5 and .netstandard 2.0....net does not support it.  Still gotta figure out how to install .netstandard2.1.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably that one of your DLLs references some part of the .net framework that is not referenced in your console application.  For example if one of your class library projects has asp.net server controls in and references System.Web, but your console application does not reference System.Web it will not build and you will get that error.  But it is not obvious because the DLLs referenced are stored in the GAC so they would never appear in your bin folder.

Comment: I think you're right Ben, I've added a full answer below - thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I had to simply restart visual studio for reference to work but make sure you have reference added in `.csproj` file.

If you still experience the issue, make sure the class you're referencing is public and that Asp.net core Framework version match.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds weird,

Have you tried to remove the reference of the project and add it again? Check if your console app has got all the right references.

You could also inspect the .csproj file and see if everything is correct in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check that you *"Class Library"* project has classes in it or if it is a data access layer project which include only a .edmx Model check the Model designer is found and it generates fine.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I worked with syncing the framework, but still, it was giving issue.
So I tried another way.
Right-click on the dependency, and select Add project reference. I added the required project then the error was gone.